# get the incremental pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, self-join, ansi-sql

I have table as below

```
  Item|Year|Price
   ---------------
  C|2010|50
  C|2000|40
  C|1999|30
  A|2010|10
  A|2009|15
  B|2018|10
  B|2017|100
  B|2015|750
  D|2018|220
  D|2017|200
  D|2016|185
```

I want to write a query so that I get only the item name which have price in incremental order every greater year.
The output of above pattern would be

```
ITEM
----
D
C
```

(D and C only have incremental price for each higher year)
I tried with self Join but I am not able the required output

Comment: Is the price allowed to be the same in one year e.g. 2009=10,2010=10,2011=15?

Comment: This is not clear. "get only the item name which have price in incremental order every greater year" is not something that tells people that that table would be output for that input. (Although I suspect we can guess what you mean.) Please use enough words & sentences to be clear, don't try to cram everything into 1 phrase or sentence. Define "incremental order" exactly. What are the CKs? (PKs & UNIQUE NOT NULL) Can there be nulls? Any other constraints? Please read & act on [mcve]. Show what parts you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this query will give you the results you want. It uses a self-join to find all years where an item has a price which is lower than a previous year. Items which have no later years where the price is lower (which will appear as i2.Item=NULL) will have a COUNT(i2.Item)=0:

```
SELECT i1.Item
FROM Items i1
LEFT JOIN Items i2 ON i2.Item = i1.Item AND i2.Price < i1.Price AND i2.Year > i1.Year
GROUP BY i1.Item
HAVING COUNT(i2.Item) = 0
```

Output:

```
Item
C
D
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34a2d4/9)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `lag` analytical function as in the following select statement :

```
select item 
  from
 (
  select sign(price - lag(price,1,0) over (order by year)) val,
         t.item
    from tab t
 ) 
 group by item
 having avg(val)=1;

 ITEM
 ----
 D
 C
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5bf90f/1)